# Sqlite-net extensions relations always null

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am trying to use the extension in MvvmCross 4. What I am trying to do is simple: I have two tables with a one to many relationship and and want to access this.

I have two classes, `BusLine` and `BusLineGroup`. Each BusLine has one Group as foreign key. What I do in code is run a simple LINQ-Query to get all Buslines:

```
var testQuery = 
    from busLine in this._connection.Table<BusLine>()
    select busLine;
```

The query itself works, but if I check the fields of the returned objects, the Group is always `null`!. See below for the class and table definitions.

[image: debug locals]

What am I doing wrong? Why is the group always `null`? Thanks for your help.

---

The classes in code:

```
    public class BusLine
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(BusLineGroup))]
        public int BusLineGroup { get; set; }
        [ManyToOne]
        public BusLineGroup LineGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class BusLineGroup
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string MainStations { get; set; }
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<BusLine> BusLines { get; set; }

    }
```

---

The two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "BusLineGroup" (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `Name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `Color` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `MainStations`  TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "BusLine" (
    `Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `Name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `BusLineGroup`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`BusLineGroup`) REFERENCES `BusLineGroup`(`Id`)
);
```

---

Installed Nuget-Packages:

- MvvmCross.Plugin.SQLitePCL
- SQLiteNetExtensions

*Note:* The MvvmCross package automatically includes SQLite.Net-PCL. So both of those two use the same PCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using any *SQLite-Net Extensions* method there, you are using plain sqlite.net methods that know nothing about your relationships. You have to use the `WithChildren` methods to read and write relationships from database.

For example, your query can be replaced with this line:

```
var testQuery = this._connection.GetAllWithChildren<BusLine>();
```

That will also fetch first-level relationships from database.

I'd recommend you to take a look at the [*SQLite-Net Extensions* documentation](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) and the [sample project](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/HEAD/IntegrationTests.Touch/?at=master) for more examples.

Comment: Don't know how I could miss that... Thanks, it works now

Comment: I get a null reference exception when I try to select records based on the criteria that a extension relationship (ManyToOne) is not null. It throws a NPE, which doesn't make sense since I am only checking if it is null, no dereferencing it. Does it have something to do with the relationship not being ready yet, when selecting?

Comment: @JamesWierzba That sounds like a different question. You can't use relationships in your queries because those properties are ignored by sqlite.net.

Comment: I'm using `GetAllWithChildren` I neglected to mention that. That is a sqlite net extension method, no? Anyway yes it should probably be its own question but I found a workaround so no worries thank you